# Java Flink External Source

Tags: java, apache-flink

I would like to have a parallel Flink source that consumes from an in-memory blocking queue. My idea is to have the application pushing elements into this queue and the Flink pipeline consumes and process them.

What is the best pattern to follow for this? I've looked at some Flink sources implementations (like Kafka, RabbitMQ, etc) and all of them are initialising the connections required from within the source instance. I cannot do this (i.e., initialise the queue from within each source instance), since

- each source instance instance would create its own queue.
- need a reference to the queue from outside of Flink to push elements to it.

Currently, I have came up with the following, but the use of static queues doesn't feel right to me.

**1. A queue from where each Flink source instance is getting its elements.**

```
public class TheQueue implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TheQueue.class);

    private transient static final BlockingQueue<Object> OBJECT_QUEUE = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public static SerializableSupplier<Object> getObjectConsumer() {
        return () -> {
            return OBJECT_QUEUE.take();
        }
    };
}
```

**2. My Flink pipeline excerpt.**

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
env.setParallelism(10);
env.addSource(TestParallelSourceFunction.getInstance(TheQueue.getObjectConsumer()))
```

**3. The Flink source function.**

```
public class TestParallelSourceFunction<T> extends RichParallelSourceFunction<T>{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestParallelSourceFunction.class);

    private SerializableSupplier<T> supplier;

    // initialisation code

    @Override
    public void run(final SourceContext<T> ctx) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info("Starting Flink source.");
        isRunning = true;

        while (isRunning) {
            final T t = supplier.get();
            if (t != null) {
                ctx.collect(t);
            }
        }

        LOGGER.info("Stopped Flink source.");
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: No, but recently found the following link which may help you. Still have to try it on my end. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Variables+Closures+vs.+Broadcast+Variables

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of message queue systems like Kafka and RabbitMQ and their role in streaming applications is flawed, I think. They are standalone services that exist outside of Flink. Flink doesn't start or configure them, it just opens connections to read from them.

So the idea would be that you start a Kafka cluster, and give the necessary connection details and topic names to both your Flink job and whatever application is pushing elements into Kafka. The application pushing elements onto the queue talks to the Kafka cluster over tcpip, and so does Flink.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (from my understanding) is that Flink takes all the operators and serializes them, sends to a "worker" which deserializes them.
This is why usually the sources are creating a connection inside of them and do not receive an external connection.

What you can do if you run the Flink pipeline inside your process (local execution environment) is to create a class which extends the RichSource function, has an ID as a serializable field and a static map between the ID and the blocking queue. It will look something like so (writing it without an IDE so syntax might be slightly off):

```
public class BlockingQueueSource<T> extends RichSourceFunction<T> {
  private static final Map<String, BlockingQueue<T>> idToQueue;

  private final String id;
  private volatile boolean isRunning;

  public BlockingQueueSource(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.isRunning = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void open(...) {
    idToQueue.put(id, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
  }

  public void close() {
    isRunning = false;
    idToQueue.remove(id);
  }

  public void run(SourceContext<T> context) {
    BlockingQueue<T> queue = idToQueue.get(id);

    while(isRunning) {
      T item = queue.take();

      context.collect(item);
    }
  }

  public void addItem(T item) {
    idToQueue.get(id).put(item);
  }
}
```

**Again, this will work only if the source is located in the same process where you created all the Flink pipeline, meaning you run it with local execution environment.**